# Html split container with buttons on the middle

Tags: html, css

I have to display 2 table and some buttons between the 2 tables to move the data from one grid to the other.

Is is possible to have 3 div where the middle one is fixed and the other 2 take the same amount of remaining space and resize based on the parent width?

Comment: Use Bootstrap / media query or calc width

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please see below you can achieve it via `calc`:

```css
.holder { height:200px;}
.item {-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; float:left; text-align:center; width: calc(50% - 150px); height:200px; border:1px solid #f00;}
.fixed-width { width:300px;}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
    <div class="item">Div 1</div>
    <div class="item fixed-width">Div 2</div>
    <div class="item">Div 3</div>
</div>
```